# How to address Chrome 80 cookie related changes with respect to iframe?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, iframe

I have a website that supports SSO and we are using iframe to invoke the logout url's of saml apps. We started seeing issues when the user clicks on logout, IDP is logging out of all service providers but due to recent chrome's cookie-related changes, cookies are not sent in the request. As cookies are not sent, logout requests are not able to identify the session and logged-in users are still logged-in. I read that we can set `SameSite` attribute to `None` to ignore Chrome 80 changes. Is there any other way to handle this case?